# How to Upgrade from Wine 5.0 to 6.0

Tags: wine, winetricks

I searched the entire web for help about how to upgrade wine from 5.0 to 6.0

My current version of wine is queried from terminal, see below:

```
Package: wine-stable
Version: 7.0.0.0~focal-1
Priority: optional
Section: otherosfs
Source: wine
Maintainer: Rosanne DiMesio <dimesio@earthlink.net>, Marcus Meissner <meissner@suse.com>
Original-Maintainer: WineHQ Builds <webmaster@fds-team.de>
Installed-Size: 13.3 MB
Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.14.12ubuntu3)
Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, libc6 (>= 2.17), wine-stable-i386 (= 7.0.0.0~focal-1), wine-stable-amd64 (= 7.0.0.0~focal-1)
```

But when I query my terminal using 'apt show wine' or 'wine --version'. I get wine 5.0 as the result.

```
Package: wine
Version: 5.0-3ubuntu1
Built-Using: khronos-api (= 4.6+git20180514-2), unicode-data (= 13.0.0-2build1)
Priority: optional
Section: universe/otherosfs
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Wine Party <debian-wine@lists.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 197 kB
Provides: wine
Depends: wine64 (>= 5.0-3ubuntu1) | wine32 (>= 5.0-3ubuntu1), wine64 (<< 5.0-3ubuntu1.1~) | wine32 (<< 5.0-3ubuntu1.1~)
Suggests: q4wine, winbind, winetricks, playonlinux, wine-binfmt, dosbox (>= 0.74-4.2~), exe-thumbnailer | kio-extras
Breaks: wine-stable (<< 3.0.1ubuntu1~)
Replaces: wine-stable (<< 3.0.1ubuntu1~)
Homepage: https://www.winehq.org
Download-Size: 51.9 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: no
APT-Sources: http://ng.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
Description: Windows API implementation - standard suite
 Wine is a free MS-Windows API implementation.
 This is still a work in progress and many applications may still not work.
 .
 This package provides essential wrappers and convenience tools for the
 standard Wine components. It also employs the Debian alternatives system to
 provide the usual command names, e.g. "wine" instead of "wine-stable".
```

Thanks for your input.

Regards

Comment: But you have "`Version: 7.0.0.0~focal-1`". 7 is greater than 6. 7 is neither the 5 or 6 in your question.

Comment: But here is my confusion, when I type this commands in terminal "apt show wine" & "wine --version", I get a different Wine 5.0 as the result, the result i get is different from the above:

```
Package: wine
Version: 5.0-3ubuntu1
Built-Using: khronos-api (= 4.6+git20180514-2), unicode-data (= 13.0.0-2build1)

```

Comment: So, it seems I am running multiple versions of wine, because, most of the applications I'm rinning seems to be running on the version 5.0 ?

Comment: wine-stable (source wine) and wine (provides wine) are not the same package. You are running wine version 5. wine 6: https://linoxide.com/how-to-install-wine6-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind How do I upgrade it.? because I am trying to avoid having multiple versions of wine installed.?

All the tutorials I see online never speaks of the upgrade of an existing version, they only speak of how to install new versions.

Comment: You remove 5 and then install 6.

Comment: Wow! I feared that because of the thought of loosing all apps installed and the settings. 

Is there a way to backup the install apps and have them restored, or do I just setup all installed software all over again.?